# I need help in selecting entire multiple lines that starts with unpackcontainer & copy that text to different text file in Notepad++

Tags: windows, notepad++, regex

I need help in selecting entire multiple lines that starts with unpackcontainer (as shown) & copy that text to different text file in Notepad++ on Windows:

```
unpackcontainer -s "\\s1-nas-colo-ca\SourceOneArchive1\Archive1\PST Archive Folder\201111\20120806095409.emx" -d "\\S1-work-colo-ca\msgcenter2$\Message_Center\Perm A\201111\20121206082430" -md5 503FD27CBA248A5F0998BE98B52E631C2DE77EA5F57F997000
unpackcontainer -s "\\s1-nas-colo-ca\SourceOneArchive1\Archive1\PST Archive Folder\201111\20121016073314.emx" -d "\\S1-work-colo-ca\msgcenter2$\Message_Center\Perm A\201111\20121206082430" -md5 50255534633E16287F8940502DB5C762892BE9AF26DC151100
unpackcontainer -s "\\s1-nas-colo-ca\SourceOneArchive1\Archive1\PST Archive Folder\201111\20121016073314.emx" -d "\\S1-work-colo-ca\msgcenter2$\Message_Center\Perm A\201111\20121206082430" -md5 5028474FAD227058D635D6EFE9EEB22AF15A79E465CF6EFB00
unpackcontainer -s "\\s1-nas-colo-ca\SourceOneArchive1\Archive1\96 Month B\201111\20130517073639.emx" -d "\\S1-work-colo-ca\msgcenter2$\Message_Center\Perm A\201111\20121206082430" -md5 502FDD8D3232B0B1C0F74BE1939F2B9740EE47E17BA7E2BA00
unpackcontainer -s "\\s1-nas-colo-ca\SourceOneArchive1\LegalHold1\Legal Hold\201111\20121207040553.emx" -d "\\S1-work-colo-ca\msgcenter2$\Message_Center\Perm A\201111\20121206082430" -md5 502543DA4EDB85F81EA2912A83642807F485B9EF1985135000
unpackcontainer -s "\\s1-nas-colo-ca\SourceOneArchive1\LegalHold1\Legal Hold\201111\20121023202413.emx" -d "\\S1-work-colo-ca\msgcenter2$\Message_Center\Perm A\201111\20121206082430" -md5 50433081C40DB471A0D64112C0C9D915D505D0AA40BF13BB00
unpackcontainer -s "\\s1-nas-colo-ca\SourceOneArchive1\Archive1\PST Archive Folder\201111\20120806095409.emx" -d "\\S1-work-colo-ca\msgcenter2$\Message_Center\Perm A\201111\20121206082430" -md5 50311C115E43FFC58D657A90F31395B070AA9743F9D58E5C00
unpackcontainer -s "\\s1-nas-colo-ca\SourceOneArchive1\LegalHold1\Legal Hold\201111\20121207103544.emx" -d "\\S1-work-colo-ca\msgcenter2$\Message_Center\Perm A\201111\20121206082430" -md5 502FE9A0E458F9F5A62856E67DF8FBB9774FCFC28C9DA0EA00
unpackcontainer -s "\\s1-nas-colo-ca\SourceOneArchive1\Archive1\PST Archive Folder\201111\20120806092215.emx" -d "\\S1-work-colo-ca\msgcenter2$\Message_Center\Perm A\201111\20121206082430" -md5 503FE564DF3B0B376CAFBF765082229961DC6F51F14089E400
unpackcontainer -s "\\s1-nas-colo-ca\SourceOneArchive1\Archive1\PST Archive Folder\201111\20120806095409.emx" -d "\\S1-work-colo-ca\msgcenter2$\Message_Center\Perm A\201111\20121206082430" -md5 5036D21649F3962061565CCCB147C8C49E820E5FF1911F5B00
```

Comment: Yes, using notepad++ on machine running windows

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++, do a `Find` on `unpackcontainer`, click the `Mark` tab on the Find box, set the `Bookmark line` option, then click `Mark All`.

You can then select menu item `Search` > `Bookmark` > `Copy Bookmarked Lines`.  The lines are then on the clipboard, so you can paste them into a separate text file.